# How to unit test Yup .test() method using React Native Testing Library?

Tags: typescript, formik, react-testing-library, yup, react-native-testing-library

I have a Formik from which is like this:

```
<Formik
   initialValues={initialValue}
   validationSchema={schema} // Here I set to the schema below. 
   onSubmit={handleBasicSubmit}
>

<FormControl isRequired isInvalid={"username" in errors}> // here if the error from schema it will shown 
     <FormControl.Label>Username</FormControl.Label>
       <Input
         p={2}
         onChangeText={handleChange("username")}
         placeholder="Preferred username"
         value={values.username}
      />
      <FormControl.ErrorMessage>
         {errors.username}
       </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
    </FormControl>

</Formik>
```

When enter username into the field, then the schema will check with server see whether the `username` is already taken by calling `checkUserHandleExist` function inside the `.test()` function.

Yup Schema:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
   username: Yup.string()
        .required('Required')
        .min(3, 'Too short')
        .max(15, 'Long')
        .matches(/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/, 'No symbol')
        .test(
          'unique-username', 
          'Already used', 
           async (value: string | undefined) =>  {
             if(value){
              try {
               const res = await checkUserHandleExist(value);

               const data = res.data;

               if (data.error) {
                 // @ts-expect-error
                 return this.createError("Have problem verify username");
               } else {
                 if (data.is_user_handle_exists) {
                   // @ts-expect-error
                   return this.createError("Already used"); // the phase should be on screen 
                 }
                 else {
                   return true;
                 }
               }
             } catch (error) { }
            }
        }
        )

})
```

In order to test it with React-Native-testing-library, here is my test:

```
it('Username enter is existed after check from server, display error', async () => {
      // here mock the API method for checkUsernameExisted 
      rest.get(API_URL + "/invite", (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(
          ctx.status(200),
          ctx.json({
            is_user_handle_exists: true  // Here mock the result is true 
          })
        )
      })
      
      const { getByText, getByPlaceholderText, queryByText } = render( 
            <UserBasicDetails />
      );
    
      const usernameField = getByPlaceholderText('Preferred username, macam Twitter or Ig')

      fireEvent.changeText(usernameField, 'kenchoong')
      const button = getByText('Continue')
      
      
      const errorMsg = queryByText(/Already used/i) // here Already used should be existed 
      expect(errorMsg).not.toBeNull()  
     
    })
```

As you can see here, I mocked the API method to return `true` as result(in Yup test function) .

Then the `errorMsg` should be existed according my code.

**Problem now**

When I `queryByText` for the `Already used` phrase, it always get this message `Error: expect(received).not.toBeNull()`.

**What I have tried:**

1. I thought I should be `wait` for the error message to show, so I tried this:

```
await waitFor(() => {
        const errorMsg = queryByText(/Already used/i) // here Already used should be existed 
        expect(errorMsg).not.toBeNull()  
      })
```

Having the same error.

2. I also tried using `getByText`, `findByText` as well. Also having this error  `Error: expect(received).not.toBeNull()`.
3. I even try without `waitFor`:

```
const errorMsg = await findByText(/Already used/i) // here Already used should be existed 
expect(errorMsg).not.toBeNull()
```

I not sure why is this happened. Since I already `waitFor` it should wait until the `errorMsg` appear. But it didnt. All my other test case for `max`, `min` and `matches` inside the Yup schema is passed, just `test` is not passed. Dont know why.

Please give some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to test schema:

```
it('should validate schema with success', async () => {
  const name = await mySchema.isValid({name: 'test'});
  expect(desc).toEqual(false);
});
```

2. To test UI:

```
it('should show length max validation errors', async () => {
  const {getByTestId, queryAllByText, queryByText} = render(component);
  const inputName: ReactTestInstance = getByTestId('inputName');
  const submit: ReactTestInstance = getByTestId('submit');
  const valName = 'b'.repeat(100);
  fireEvent.changeText(inputName, valName);
  
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(queryAllByText("Your name is out of char limit")).not.toBeNull();
    expect(submit.props.accessibilityState.disabled).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```